# Given a language $L_1$ over the $\Sigma$ alphabet, is the following statement correct?

Tags: formal-languages

Given a language $L_1$ over $\Sigma$ alphabet, is
$L_1L_1^*L_1=L_1^*L_1^2\cap L_1^2\Sigma^*$

Correct?
I started by simplifing the expression to : $L_1^*= L_1^*\cap L_1^2\Sigma^*$
Now, my problem was understanding the right side. I think the statement is correct, because $L_1^*\subseteq \Sigma^*$, so $L_1^*\cap L_1^2\Sigma^*=L_1^*\cap L_1^*=L_1^*$
Is that right?

Comment: It is not true in general that $L^*=L^*\cap L^2\Sigma^*$. For example, if $L=\{a\}$,  then the empty string is an element of $L^*$ but not of $L^*\cap L^2\Sigma^*$.

Comment: So my simplification is not correct?

Comment: x @Yin: Agreed, something is wrong with your simplification, because if $L=\{a\}$, then $LL^*L$ and $L^*L^2\cap L^2\Sigma^*$ are indeed equal (both are the language $\{a^n\mid n\ge 2\}$).

Comment: You're probably better off _not_ trying to simplify, but just showing inclusions in both directions between your two original expressions.

Comment: So I understand you think this statement is correct?

Comment: x @Yin: Yes -- intuitively, both expressions denote the language $\{w_1w_2\cdots w_n\mid n\ge 2, w_i\in L \}$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as a single calculation rather than by showing that each side is a subset of the other:

$$\begin{align*}
L_1^*L_1^2\cap L_1^2\Sigma^*&=\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 0}L_1^nL_1^2\right)\cap\bigcup_{n\ge 0}L_1^2\Sigma^n\\
&=\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 2}L_1^n\right)\cap\bigcup_{n\ge 0}L_1^2\Sigma^n\\
&=\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 0}L_1^2L_1^n\right)\cap\bigcup_{n\ge 0} L_1^2\Sigma^n\\
&=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}\bigcup_{m\ge 0}(L_1^2L_1^n\cap L_1^2\Sigma^m)\\
&=L_1^2\bigcup_{n\ge 0}\bigcup_{m\ge 0}(L_1^n\cap\Sigma^m)\\
&=L_1^2\bigcup_{n\ge 0}L_1^n\\
&=\bigcup_{n\ge 2}L_1^n\\
&=L_1\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 0}L_1\right)L_1\\
&=L_1L_1^*L_1
\end{align*}$$